# lib for configuration handling in an ergonomic way

Tags: configuration, rust

I'm writing a common library for loading and handling configuration for my applications,
 using the [config crate](https://crates.io/crates/config).

Im trying to make it as ergonomic as possible to the user, but can't seem to figure it out.

my lib.rs:

```
impl RunEnv {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            RunEnv::Production => "prod".to_string(),
            RunEnv::Dev => "dev".to_string(),
            RunEnv::Staging => "stag".to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl FromStr for RunEnv {
    type Err = String;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<RunEnv, String> {
        match s {
            "dev" => Ok(RunEnv::Dev),
            "stag" => Ok(RunEnv::Staging),
            "prod" => Ok(RunEnv::Production),
            _ => Err(format!("Could not parse {:?}", s)),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "CLI Options", about = "Common CLI options for running applications")]
pub struct Arguments {
    /// Run in a specific environment mode: dev, stag, prod.
    // short and long flags (-e, --env) will be deduced from the field's name
    #[structopt(short, long, default_value = "dev")]
    pub env: RunEnv,
}

pub trait LoadConfig {
    fn new() -> Result<Config, ConfigError>{
        const PACKAGE_NAME: &'static str = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME");
        let mut s = Config::new();
        let args = Arguments::from_args();

        let mut conf_path = String::new();
        match args.env {
            RunEnv::Production => {
                conf_path = format!("/path/to/config/{}/config.toml", PACKAGE_NAME);
            }
            RunEnv::Staging => {
                conf_path = format!("/path/to/config/{}/config.toml", PACKAGE_NAME);
            }
            RunEnv::Dev => {
                conf_path = "tests/config.toml".to_string();
            }
        }

        // Start off by merging in the "default" configuration file
        s.merge(File::with_name(&conf_path))?;

        // Add in the current environment
        // Default to 'dev' env  
        s.set("run_mode", args.env.to_string())?;

        Ok(s)
    }
}
```

In my app:

setting.rs

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Server {
    port: u32,
    address: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Settings {
   server: Server,
   run_mode: Option<String>,
}
impl LoadConfig for Settings {}
```

main.rs

```
fn main() {
    let conf: Settings = Settings::new().unwrap().try_into().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", conf);
```

And **here is my problem,** I'm trying to "hide" the`.unwrap().try_into().unwrap();` part away
so the lib user will only need to define his `setting.rs` and run `let conf: Settings = Settings::new()`

If i move `.try_into()` inside a trait then I'm getting an error i can't find a way to go around:

```
   |         s.try_into()
   |           ^^^^^^^^ the trait `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Configuration::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `config::config::Config`
```

I'm new to rust and probably missing some obvious things

Answer (score 1):

For convention the `new` function is the way to build an instance and must be an inherent method of the struct,
a method available directly on a type.

In your example you are trying to define `new` as a trait default method.
If it was at all possible the signature should be:

```
pub trait LoadConfig {
  fn new() -> Self {

  }
}
```

Such trait method is impossible to implement because the trait does not know nothing about `Self` concrete type.

To follow this convention it is best to rename the `LoadConfig::new` trait method to something else:

```
pub trait LoadConfig {
  fn load() -> Result<Config, ConfigError>;
}
```

Then implement the new constructor function as an inherent method, for example:

```
impl Settings {

    fn new() -> Settings {
        let config = Settings::load().unwrap(); // TBD: manage errors

        let port: u32 = config.get("port").unwrap_or("8080").parse().unwrap();

        Settings {
            server: Server {
                port: port,
                address: config.get("address").unwrap_or("localhost").to_owned()
            },
            run_mode: None
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a robust implementation should not `unwrap` but manage more explicitly config errors.

Comment: thanks for the answer, didn't you mean to write `impl LoadConfig for Settings`?  

im trying to keep all the logic and error handling in the trait if possible, because configuration loading will be the same everywhere, and i hate to have the same code in every app (the impl part).

Comment: No, you need a `new` inherent method or a way to build your app structs and it is not possible to use a default method trait.
I've update the answer, I hope it helps.
There is not much logic in new impl, and it is just an example, config shold be passed as an argument, ecc. ecc.